# Is it possible to make a cross origin request to a web page where I have no control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

Im trying to make a an Ajax call to https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/sdn_advanced.xml but I keep getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Considering I have absolutely no control over the source of this information is this request actually possible? Do I just need the right configuration for my request or is this physically impossible?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sanctions/1.0/sdn_advanced.xml',
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: how about trying the normal http, might be the https is blocking the request.

Comment: I get a 307 Internal Redirect to the https version if i try that. So i guess thats not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as you have no access to source API and source may not have CORS enabled.

Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. It is required that CORS is enabled for the source file. You can check more here regarding same origin policy.: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected. It seems that this is possible in some way though, is it perhaps a case of writing a server that can access this information and act as a middle man of some sorts?

Comment: It is possible for the CORS enabled source which is not protected by security methods.

Comment: For anyone who finds this there is a way to achieve this. You must use a server as a 'middle man' to get the data. Something like node.js will get around the CORS issues.